# https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/followedSites not working anymore

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, csom

I have an application that uses MS Graph. The registered application has all these rights:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqekt.png)

The problem is that I get an error.

If I add User.Read then it works, but based on the documentation it should work with Sites.ReadWrite.All

Graph explorer works OK but inspecting the token, it well has User.Read.

Thanks

It should work with the default permissions.

Comment: Could you share the error?

Comment: It is 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering an error when trying to access SharePoint files using Microsoft Graph with the Sites.ReadWrite.All permission, it's possible that there could be a few reasons for this issue.

Comment: Hi RaytheonXie-MSFT.. but the documentation says that with this permission it should be enough